# Realtek 8168 script don't works

Tags: realtek

i want using up to date Realtek drivers but with Ubuntu 22 i just can't made it.
The Realtek script removed old open source driver and i've just USB tether with my phone.
Here is Realtek logs:

```
make -C src/ clean
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/deb/Downloads/r8168-8.050.03/src'
make -C /lib/modules/5.15.0-41-generic/build M=/home/deb/Downloads/r8168-8.050.03/src clean
make[2]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.0-41-generic'
  CLEAN   /home/deb/Downloads/r8168-8.050.03/src/Module.symvers
make[2]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.0-41-generic'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/deb/Downloads/r8168-8.050.03/src'
make -C src/ modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/deb/Downloads/r8168-8.050.03/src'
make -C /lib/modules/5.15.0-41-generic/build M=/home/deb/Downloads/r8168-8.050.03/src modules
make[2]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.0-41-generic'
  CC [M]  /home/deb/Downloads/r8168-8.050.03/src/r8168_n.o
  CC [M]  /home/deb/Downloads/r8168-8.050.03/src/r8168_asf.o
  CC [M]  /home/deb/Downloads/r8168-8.050.03/src/rtl_eeprom.o
  CC [M]  /home/deb/Downloads/r8168-8.050.03/src/rtltool.o
  LD [M]  /home/deb/Downloads/r8168-8.050.03/src/r8168.o
  MODPOST /home/deb/Downloads/r8168-8.050.03/src/Module.symvers
  CC [M]  /home/deb/Downloads/r8168-8.050.03/src/r8168.mod.o
  LD [M]  /home/deb/Downloads/r8168-8.050.03/src/r8168.ko
  BTF [M] /home/deb/Downloads/r8168-8.050.03/src/r8168.ko
make[2]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.0-41-generic'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/deb/Downloads/r8168-8.050.03/src'
make -C src/ install
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/deb/Downloads/r8168-8.050.03/src'
make -C /lib/modules/5.15.0-41-generic/build M=/home/deb/Downloads/r8168-8.050.03/src INSTALL_MOD_DIR=kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/realtek modules_install
make[2]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.0-41-generic'
  INSTALL /lib/modules/5.15.0-41-generic/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/realtek/r8168.ko
  SIGN    /lib/modules/5.15.0-41-generic/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/realtek/r8168.ko
  DEPMOD  /lib/modules/5.15.0-41-generic
make[2]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.0-41-generic'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/deb/Downloads/r8168-8.050.03/src'
```

Here is shell output:

```
deb@deb:~/Downloads/r8168-8.050.03$ sudo bash autorun.sh

Check old driver and unload it. 
Build the module and install 
Skipping BTF generation for /home/deb/Downloads/r8168-8.050.03/src/r8168.ko due to unavailability of vmlinux 
arch/x86/Makefile:142: CONFIG_X86_X32 enabled but no binutils support 
At main.c:160:
    - SSL error:FFFFFFFF80000002:system library::No such file or directory: ../crypto/bio/bss_file.c:67
    - SSL error:10000080:BIO routines::no such file: ../crypto/bio/bss_file.c:75 
sign-file: certs/signing_key.pem: No such file or directory 
Warning: modules_install: missing 'System.map' file. Skipping depmod. 
DEPMOD 5.15.0-41-generic 
load module r8168 
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'r8168': Operation not permitted 
Updating initramfs. Please wait. 
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-41-generic Completed.
```

Lspci -k

```
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
Kernel modules: r8168
```

in nmcli there is no enp2s0

I don't know why there is painfull things every time i want to try Linux but it's happened anyway.

Some suggestions?

Edit ================================

Thank you for informative answer @telcoM
But things get worse. I've MOK files but:

```
deb@deb:~$ sudo ls /var/lib/shim-signed/mok
MOK.der  MOK.priv

deb@deb:~$ ls /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/realtek
8139cp.ko  8139too.ko  atp.ko  r8168.ko  r8169.bak

deb@deb:~$ sudo kmodsign sha512 \ /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.priv \ /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.der \ /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/realtek/r8168.ko
At main.c:249:
- SSL error:FFFFFFFF80000002:system library::No such file or directory: ../crypto/bio/bss_file.c:67
- SSL error:10000080:BIO routines::no such file: ../crypto/bio/bss_file.c:75
kmodsign:  /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.priv: No such file or directory
```

So i looked up openssl:

```
deb@deb:~$ ls /usr/lib/ssl/
certs  misc  openssl.cnf  private
```

I said naybe reinstalling helps but apt removed also Chrome and a lot of things.

```
deb@deb:~$ sudo apt-get remove openssl
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  apport-symptoms apturl-common cups-server-common gir1.2-dbusmenu-glib-0.4 gir1.2-dee-1.0 gir1.2-goa-1.0 gir1.2-snapd-1 gir1.2-unity-7.0
  gnome-software-common hplip-data libauthen-sasl-perl libclone-perl libcupsimage2 libdata-dump-perl libfile-listing-perl libflatpak0
  libfont-afm-perl libglu1-mesa libhpmud0 libhtml-form-perl libhtml-format-perl libhtml-parser-perl libhtml-tagset-perl libhtml-tree-perl
  libhttp-cookies-perl libhttp-daemon-perl libhttp-date-perl libhttp-message-perl libhttp-negotiate-perl libimagequant0 libio-html-perl
  libio-socket-ssl-perl liblwp-mediatypes-perl libmailtools-perl libnet-http-perl libnet-smtp-ssl-perl libnet-ssleay-perl libraqm0
  libsane-hpaio libtie-ixhash-perl libtimedate-perl libtry-tiny-perl libvncclient1 libwww-robotrules-perl libxatracker2
  libxml-xpathengine-perl libxvmc1 perl-openssl-defaults printer-driver-postscript-hp python3-blinker python3-cffi-backend python3-chardet
  python3-cryptography python3-dateutil python3-debconf python3-debian python3-distro-info python3-distupgrade python3-idna python3-jeepney
  python3-jwt python3-keyring python3-lazr.uri python3-nacl python3-oauthlib python3-olefile python3-pexpect python3-pil
  python3-problem-report python3-protobuf python3-ptyprocess python3-pymacaroons python3-pyparsing python3-renderpm python3-reportlab
  python3-reportlab-accel python3-rfc3339 python3-secretstorage python3-six python3-systemd python3-tz python3-update-manager
  python3-urllib3 python3-wadllib ubuntu-advantage-desktop-daemon unattended-upgrades x11-apps x11-session-utils xbitmaps xinit xinput
  xserver-xorg-input-all xserver-xorg-input-libinput xserver-xorg-input-wacom xserver-xorg-video-all xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu
  xserver-xorg-video-ati xserver-xorg-video-fbdev xserver-xorg-video-intel xserver-xorg-video-nouveau xserver-xorg-video-qxl
  xserver-xorg-video-radeon xserver-xorg-video-vesa xserver-xorg-video-vmware
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  apport apport-gtk apturl bluez-cups ca-certificates cups cups-browsed cups-core-drivers cups-daemon gnome-online-accounts gnome-software
  gnome-software-plugin-flatpak gnome-software-plugin-snap google-chrome-stable hplip liblwp-protocol-https-perl libnet-dbus-perl libtpms0
  libwww-perl libxml-parser-perl libxml-twig-perl nautilus-share openssl printer-driver-hpcups printer-driver-splix python3-apport
  python3-certifi python3-httplib2 python3-launchpadlib python3-lazr.restfulclient python3-macaroonbakery python3-requests
  python3-software-properties snapd software-properties-common software-properties-gtk ssl-cert swtpm swtpm-tools ubuntu-desktop
  ubuntu-desktop-minimal ubuntu-release-upgrader-core ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk update-manager update-manager-core update-notifier
  update-notifier-common x11vnc xorg xserver-xorg
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 50 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After this operation, 397 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 197839 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing apport-gtk (2.20.11-0ubuntu82.1) ...
Removing apport (2.20.11-0ubuntu82.1) ...
Removing nautilus-share (0.7.3-2ubuntu6) ...
Removing apturl (0.5.2ubuntu22) ...
Removing bluez-cups (5.64-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing google-chrome-stable (103.0.5060.134-1) ...
Removing ubuntu-desktop (1.481) ...
Removing printer-driver-splix (2.0.0+svn315-7fakesync1build3) ...
Removing hplip (3.21.12+dfsg0-1) ...
Removing printer-driver-hpcups (3.21.12+dfsg0-1) ...
Removing cups (2.4.1op1-1ubuntu4.1) ...
Removing cups-browsed (1.28.15-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing cups-core-drivers (2.4.1op1-1ubuntu4.1) ...
Removing cups-daemon (2.4.1op1-1ubuntu4.1) ...
Removing gnome-online-accounts (3.44.0-1ubuntu1) ...
Removing gnome-software-plugin-flatpak (41.5-2) ...
Removing gnome-software-plugin-snap (41.5-2) ...
Removing gnome-software (41.5-2) ...
Removing libnet-dbus-perl (1.2.0-1build3) ...
Removing libxml-twig-perl (1:3.52-1) ...
Removing libxml-parser-perl:amd64 (2.46-3build1) ...
Removing swtpm-tools (0.6.3-0ubuntu3) ...
Removing swtpm (0.6.3-0ubuntu3) ...
Removing libtpms0:amd64 (0.9.3-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing x11vnc (0.9.16-8) ...
Removing ssl-cert (1.1.2) ...
Removing ubuntu-desktop-minimal (1.481) ...
Removing xorg (1:7.7+23ubuntu2) ...
Removing xserver-xorg (1:7.7+23ubuntu2) ...
Removing python3-apport (2.20.11-0ubuntu82.1) ...
Removing python3-macaroonbakery (1.3.1-2) ...
Removing python3-requests (2.25.1+dfsg-2) ...
Removing python3-certifi (2020.6.20-1) ...
Removing software-properties-gtk (0.99.22.2) ...
Removing software-properties-common (0.99.22.2) ...
Removing python3-software-properties (0.99.22.2) ...
Removing python3-launchpadlib (1.10.16-1) ...
Removing python3-lazr.restfulclient (0.14.4-1) ...
Removing python3-httplib2 (0.20.2-2) ...
Removing snapd (2.55.5+22.04) ...
Warning: Stopping snapd.service, but it can still be activated by:
  snapd.socket
Removing liblwp-protocol-https-perl (6.10-1) ...
Removing libwww-perl (6.61-1) ...
Removing update-notifier (3.192.54) ...
Removing update-manager (1:22.04.9) ...
Removing update-notifier-common (3.192.54) ...
Removing update-manager-core (1:22.04.9) ...
Removing ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk (1:22.04.11) ...
Removing ubuntu-release-upgrader-core (1:22.04.11) ...
Removing ca-certificates (20211016) ...
Removing dangling symlinks from /etc/ssl/certs... done.
Removing openssl (3.0.2-0ubuntu1.6) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.36.0-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for libglib2.0-0:amd64 (2.72.1-1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.35-0ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.10.2-1) ...
Processing triggers for dbus (1.12.20-2ubuntu4) ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (2.1-2) ...
Processing triggers for mailcap (3.70+nmu1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.26-1ubuntu3) ...
```

and

```
deb@deb:~$ sudo apt-get install openssl
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  apport-symptoms apturl-common cups-server-common gir1.2-dbusmenu-glib-0.4 gir1.2-dee-1.0 gir1.2-goa-1.0 gir1.2-snapd-1 gir1.2-unity-7.0
  gnome-software-common hplip-data libauthen-sasl-perl libclone-perl libcupsimage2 libdata-dump-perl libfile-listing-perl libflatpak0
  libfont-afm-perl libglu1-mesa libhpmud0 libhtml-form-perl libhtml-format-perl libhtml-parser-perl libhtml-tagset-perl libhtml-tree-perl
  libhttp-cookies-perl libhttp-daemon-perl libhttp-date-perl libhttp-message-perl libhttp-negotiate-perl libimagequant0 libio-html-perl
  libio-socket-ssl-perl liblwp-mediatypes-perl libmailtools-perl libnet-http-perl libnet-smtp-ssl-perl libnet-ssleay-perl libraqm0
  libsane-hpaio libtie-ixhash-perl libtimedate-perl libtry-tiny-perl libvncclient1 libwww-robotrules-perl libxatracker2
  libxml-xpathengine-perl libxvmc1 perl-openssl-defaults printer-driver-postscript-hp python3-blinker python3-cffi-backend python3-chardet
  python3-cryptography python3-dateutil python3-debconf python3-debian python3-distro-info python3-distupgrade python3-idna python3-jeepney
  python3-jwt python3-keyring python3-lazr.uri python3-nacl python3-oauthlib python3-olefile python3-pexpect python3-pil
  python3-problem-report python3-protobuf python3-ptyprocess python3-pymacaroons python3-pyparsing python3-renderpm python3-reportlab
  python3-reportlab-accel python3-rfc3339 python3-secretstorage python3-six python3-systemd python3-tz python3-update-manager
  python3-urllib3 python3-wadllib ubuntu-advantage-desktop-daemon unattended-upgrades x11-apps x11-session-utils xbitmaps xinit xinput
  xserver-xorg-input-all xserver-xorg-input-libinput xserver-xorg-input-wacom xserver-xorg-video-all xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu
  xserver-xorg-video-ati xserver-xorg-video-fbdev xserver-xorg-video-intel xserver-xorg-video-nouveau xserver-xorg-video-qxl
  xserver-xorg-video-radeon xserver-xorg-video-vesa xserver-xorg-video-vmware
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
Suggested packages:
  ca-certificates
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  openssl
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/1.184 kB of archives.
After this operation, 2.102 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package openssl.
(Reading database ... 195686 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../openssl_3.0.2-0ubuntu1.6_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking openssl (3.0.2-0ubuntu1.6) ...
Setting up openssl (3.0.2-0ubuntu1.6) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.10.2-1) ...
```

I don't know what is the Ubuntu private signage keys? Maybe problem is '..crypto/' directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have Secure Boot enabled, and whoever maintains that driver package apparently wasn't aware of the Secure Boot requirements, or simply didn't care.

Is this the driver you tried to install? https://github.com/mtorromeo/r8168

These messages might be harmless:

```
Skipping BTF generation for /home/deb/Downloads/r8168-8.050.03/src/r8168.ko due to unavailability of vmlinux 
arch/x86/Makefile:142: CONFIG_X86_X32 enabled but no binutils support
```

But this message indicates the kernel is configured to sign all the standard modules for use with Secure Boot enabled, and the driver is trying to use the same procedure, but failing because you naturally don't have Ubuntu's private signing key:

```
At main.c:160:
    - SSL error:FFFFFFFF80000002:system library::No such file or directory: ../crypto/bio/bss_file.c:67
    - SSL error:10000080:BIO routines::no such file: ../crypto/bio/bss_file.c:75 
sign-file: certs/signing_key.pem: No such file or directory
```

This means the resulting module will be unsigned, and so Secure Boot-enabled systems must reject it.

You could fix it yourself with the following steps:

1. If you don't already have a Secure Boot MOK (Machine Owner's Key) created, create it now:

```
sudo update-secureboot-policy --new-key
```

If there is already an existing MOK (i.e. `/var/lib/shim-signed/mok/` directory exists and is not empty) then you can skip this step to use it instead.

If during the installation of Ubuntu 22, you activated the option "Install third-party software for graphics and Wi-Fi hardware and additional media formats" and its sub-option "Configure Secure Boot", then you should already have an existing MOK created for you. In this case, you should NOT create a new MOK, as it might cause problems with other third-party drivers your system may already be using.

2. Use the `kmodsign` command to sign the module:

```
sudo kmodsign sha512 \
    /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.priv \
    /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.der \
    /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/net/r8168.ko
```

3. Update your initramfs:

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

4. If you created a new MOK in step 1, you'll need to do the MOK enrollment procedure. It begins by running this command, which will require you to create a new MOK enrollment password:

```
sudo mokutil --import /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.der
```

After this command is completed, you must reboot. The `shimx64.efi` will interrupt the boot process with a blue screen that says `Perform MOK management` at the top. You should select the "Enroll MOK" option, confirm it, then enter the MOK enrollment password you just created with the command above. If successful, you should see a small menu with "Reboot" as the top item. Select it and the system should boot normally, with a Secure Boot-signed `r8168.ko` module.

After the MOK enrollment is successfully completed, the MOK enrollment password will *never again be needed*: if the MOK needs to be re-enrolled (possibly after a BIOS flashing), a new enrollment password will be set for that operation.

Whenever your system receives a kernel update, the new kernel may again fail to load the r8168.ko module. If that happens, you must manually rebuild this driver:

1. `cd` to the directory you extracted the driver package into:

```
cd ~/Downloads/r8168-8.050.03
```

2. Re-run the `autorun.sh`:

```
sudo bash autorun.sh
```

3. Sign the rebuilt module: (wrapped to multiple lines for readability: remove the backslashes to enter this command as a single command line)

```
sudo kmodsign sha512 \
    /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.priv \
    /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.der \
    /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/net/r8168.ko
```

4. Update your initramfs:

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

And yes, this could be automated, if the driver package maintainer would update the package to use the DKMS system.

Comment: Hİ @telcoM
I made a edit on post. Please feel free to check it.

Comment: If you enter the `sudo kmodsign` command as a single line, remove the backslashes: `sudo kmodsign sha512 /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.priv /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.der /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/realtek/r8168.ko`

Comment: Thanks @telcoM You're pro. It works. So why script can't do this basic thing? İ'm using secure boot since ubuntu install already

Comment: That's something that should be asked from the person who packaged the driver for distribution (maybe they didn't have any experience with Secure Boot?). Perhaps you could improve the `autorun.sh` script yourself, and/or add a `dkms.conf` to the driver package (see `man dkms` for instructions).